# Spring - update java classes base on XML bean definition

Tags: java, spring, auto-update

We are using Spring 3, all of our bean declarations and property mappings are done through XML.  I've been tasked to update the java classes to use the `@Resource` where needed. We have a lot of classes.

We use Eclipse for the IDE.

I've never written a script to update Java code, so thought I'd ask for some suggestion on how to approach the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: hundreds - it's a very big application.  Would take quite some time to do it by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue converting legacy EJB `@Stateless` services to Spring beans - hundreds of them and I didn't want to change all just to add `@Bean` or `@Service` annotations.

I found the component-scan util to be most useful:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.businessservices">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.ejb.Stateless"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

See what other options of available for the filter type and expressions, and use one that matches your criteria to identifying your classes that need to be beans.